# Writing php in a way that allows

Tags: php

Hello I was wondering if it was possible to write php this way, first I am going to show the correct way to write. Here is my code:

```
$message = "<p style='font-size:16px; color:red;'>Hello world!</p>";
```

But I want to write it this way. Here is my code:

```
$message = " ?> <p style='font-size:16px; color:red;'>Hello world!</p> <? ";
```

How can I write my code in php that way?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? And yes your second example will work, except it'll actually output the `?> <?` tags to the page, which isn't correct HTML and will confuse some browsers and/or mess up the page layout.

Comment: Eh? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Basically write it in HTML so I wont have to change the quotation marks every time

Comment: I am little puzzled by what You want to achieve, but maybe `HEREDOC` is what You are looking for? See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: You would like to use `"` in your echo statements ? Fine, just use `'` to delimit the actual string, or escape the quotes with "\" every time. Examples : `echo 'Hello "quote" world'` or `echo "Hello \"quote\" world"`.

Comment: I have HERODOC but that does  not work

Comment: I kinda like the idea of a hero doc.

Comment: I don't understand. If your question is about quotation marks why did you add ?> and <? to your example??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically write it in HTML so I wont have to change the quotation marks every time

Use [HereDoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax then

```
$html=<<<HTML

<p style='font-size:16px; color:red;'>Hello world!</p>
<p>
You don't have to worry about single quotes ' or double quotes "
</p>

HTML;
```

Comment: Ok can we see an example of yours where heredoc is not working for you?

Comment: Make absolutely sure that there are no spaces etc. before `HTML;` or whatever it is you're using as a closing word. @user3342705 Use it "exactly" as shown in Hanky's answer.

Comment: Yes store php content on a PHP string

Comment: Why would you want to make such a spaghetti?

Comment: Because its easiest to write HTML code than to change the html code

Comment: Sorry I wont be able to be of any further help. That's not how good PHP code is written. I can delete my answer if you wish